# Way To Create .hide() and .show() in Plain Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

Avoiding jQuery altogether, I set out today to try and make myself something like:

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

And the goal would be that it would apply `.style.display = 'none'` to `#myDiv`.

So, we learn that the following makes a slightly similar selector to jQuery:

```
var $ = s => document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)(s).length > 1 ?
  document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)(s) : document.querySelector.bind(document)(s);
```

Just be careful in using it because it can return multiple elements, of which you may need to use the `.forEach(function(el,i){el.doSomething();});` syntax on.

So, I tried to create an easy `$(...).hide()` function like so:

```
$.__proto__.hide = function(){this.forEach(function(el,i){el.style.display='none';});};
```

Unfortunately, `__proto__` is now deprecated, and even if you disregard that, the above won't work unless you do something like this:

```
$('#myDIV').__proto__.hide = function(){this.forEach(function(el,i){el.style.display='none';});};
```

What is the technique to extend my `$` object with a `.hide()` function using plain vanilla Javascript?

Comment: There are numerous good articles to be found searching the web for "how to write your own jquery" or some such.  This one seems to cover the basics well: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-create-your-own-vanilla-js-dom-manipulation-library-like-jquery/

Comment: See here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that you directly return the `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` result. You could wrap it within your own class that you can easily extend with methods.

```
class ElementsHelper {
  constructor(elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
  }

  // helper to simplify iterating `this.elements` and returning `this`
  forEach(fn) {
    this.elements.forEach(fn);
    return this;
  }

  hide() {
    return this.forEach(element => element.style.display = "none");
  }

  click(fn) {
    return this.forEach(element => element.addEventListener("click", fn));
  }

}

function $(selector) {
  return new ElementsHelper(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
```

With the above you could now do:

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

Comment: Can't believe I left that option out of my list. :-) It's been a really long week.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have <s>two</s> choices:

1. Use your own object like jQuery does, or
2. Extend a built-in prototype.
3. Extend each individual result object as you return it; see [3limin4t0r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361113/157247)

I'd probably use approach #1, perhaps extending `Array` (or using an array via composition).

You seem to preer approach #2. It's usually not recommended because as soon as you start combining scripts from multiple locations, you run into potential conflicts. But within an *app* (rather than library), it's not necessarily unreasonable.

In your case, if your `$` function returns the result of `querySelectorAll`, it returns a `NodeList`, and you can extend `NodeList.prototype`. Whenever extending a prototype, always use `Object.defineProperty` (or similar) to define a *non-enumerable* property. For instance:

```
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "hide", {
    value() {
        this.forEach(/*...*/);
        return this;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Live Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "hide", {
    value() {
        // This isn't a great "hide", it's just for
        // the purposes of showing the plumbing
        this.forEach(el => el.style.display = "none");
        return this;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

const $ = selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector);

setTimeout(() => {
    $(".a").hide();
    console.log("Hid .a elements");
}, 800);
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

---

> Unfortunately, `__proto__` is now deprecated

That's true, but `Object.getPrototypeOf` isn't, just the `__proto__` accessor property (it was only added to the spec for backward-compatibility).